# Writing a header from the value of a column in Excel

Tags: excel, printing, excel-2007

My Excel sheet has 500 pages. In column 'm' is the country name such as Japan, Germany etc. but it is the same in each page. When it changes country it inserts page breaks I have limit  of print area I want this country printed on the header of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you **cannont set a custom header on each page** (you could probably find a very heavy solution through vba but that would be an ugly one).

Maybe, you could adapt your worksheets to **print head row on every page**: http://www.lytebyte.com/2009/08/18/how-to-print-first-row-or-header-row-on-every-page-in-excel/